# What kind of USB cable do I need for my Arduino NANO 33 BLE W/ HEADERS?

Tags: arduino-nano

I have recently purchased an Arduino Nano from the main site, but it did not come with a USB cable for programming it. I have also checked out the Arduino site and there was no reference for what type of cable I needed. I saw that there was a USB 2.0 CABLE TYPE A/B on the site but I'm not sure that it is the one that I require.

Does anyone know which cable I should buy? Thank you in advance!

Edit: To clarify, I checked out the Arduino Store https://store.arduino.cc/usa/

Comment: what is `main site`? .... we have no idea what you bought ... please provide a link or a picture ....  check this out https://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb

Comment: On [Arduino.cc Store](https://store.arduino.cc/nano-33-ble) I see a Micro USB port on the image